# Why does changing CSS variables in JS break the app?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I want to implement a text switch with CSS as outlined in https://css-tricks.com/swapping-out-text-five-different-ways/#aa-css-only-way:

```css
:root {
    --release-version: "R0.0.0";
    --build-version: "v0.0.0";
}

/* https://css-tricks.com/swapping-out-text-five-different-ways/#aa-css-only-way */
#app-version {
    position: relative;
}
#app-version-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
#app-version-checkbox:checked + #app-version::after {
    content: var(--build-version);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<input id="app-version-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<label for="app-version-checkbox" id="app-version">R0.0.0</label>
```

which as you can see, is working.

But what I really want is to be able to update the versions:

```js
//TODO: get versions from a config file or something
let releaseVersion = "R1.1.0"
let buildVersion = "v1.32.0"

window.onload = () => {
    const root = document.querySelector(":root");
    root.style.setProperty("--release-version", releaseVersion)
    root.style.setProperty("--build-version", buildVersion)
    
    //cannot change label text with CSS
    document.querySelector("#app-version").innerHTML = releaseVersion
}
```

```css
:root {
    --release-version: "R0.0.0";
    --build-version: "v0.0.0";
}

/* https://css-tricks.com/swapping-out-text-five-different-ways/#aa-css-only-way */
#app-version {
    position: relative;
}
#app-version-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
#app-version-checkbox:checked + #app-version::after {
    content: var(--build-version);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<input id="app-version-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<label for="app-version-checkbox" id="app-version"></label>
```

and that doesn't work.

So at first, I thought I'm just stupid and I'm not supposed to use `innerHTML` and that broke something, but even if I don't do that:

```js
//TODO: get versions from a config file or something
let releaseVersion = "R1.1.0"
let buildVersion = "v1.32.0"

window.onload = () => {
    const root = document.querySelector(":root");
    root.style.setProperty("--release-version", releaseVersion)
    root.style.setProperty("--build-version", buildVersion)
}
```

```css
:root {
    --release-version: "R0.0.0";
    --build-version: "v0.0.0";
}

/* https://css-tricks.com/swapping-out-text-five-different-ways/#aa-css-only-way */
#app-version {
    position: relative;
}
#app-version-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
#app-version-checkbox:checked + #app-version::after {
    content: var(--build-version);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<input id="app-version-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<label for="app-version-checkbox" id="app-version">R0.0.0</label>
```

That still doesn't work.

It's the act of setting the variables that breaks the app, and if I inspect the snippet, I also notice that the override is weird, too:

[image: overrides aren't set correctly]

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I just don't see it.

What is going on, here?

(And yes, I do realise that since I'm now using JS anyway, I could just use a button, but I want to understand why this is happening.)

EDIT: doing it with CSS variables would also allow me to do things like

```
.release-version::after {
    content: var(--release-version);
}
```

which would be nice.

Comment: Why are you trying to update text with CSS variables?

Comment: @Dominic because ideally, I just want to update the property and then have it propagated everywhere it's used - which html doesn't allow and doing everything in JS would be a hassle if I can just toss a class onto an element and let CSS sort it out, instead. (see edit)

Comment: JS can easily change the text content of, say, any element with a given class. How is this a hassle, especially compared to the time you've already spent trying to solve this CSS problem?

Comment: I assume it's not just a case of changing `let releaseVersion = "R1.1.0"
let buildVersion = "v1.32.0"` to `let releaseVersion = """R1.1.0"""
let buildVersion = """v1.32.0"""`

Comment: You have lost the quotes that the CSS content property requires - as can be seen from the values before you update them. Put some quotes into your string and all should be well.

Comment: How widespread is this text even going to be? Is it supposed to be different for different users or something?

Comment: The override is exactly as expected. You're specifically setting the inline style of the root element (= `<html>`) when you do `root.style.setProperty(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS variables are copied as they are from where they are defined to the place where they are used. It is mostly just a dynamic copy and paste which is why stuff like that works:

```css
:root {
   --color: 255,0,;
   --comma: ,;
}

div {
   color: rgba(var(--color) 5 var(--comma) 0.5);
}
```

When you do:

```js
root.style.setProperty("--release-version", releaseVersion)
root.style.setProperty("--build-version", buildVersion)
```

It would result into this:

```css
:root {
   --release-version: R1.1.0;
   --build-version: v1.32.0;
}
```

I mean you would expect that `root.style.setProperty("--color", "red")` results into `--release-version: red;` and not into `--release-version: "red";`. But the text has to be quoted, so you somehow need to add the quotes around the text.

You could utilize `JSON.stringify` to convert the string a textual representation with those quotes that are required, which would also allow to `"` in the contents of the value:

```js
//TODO: get versions from a config file or something
let releaseVersion = 'R1.1.0"'
let buildVersion = 'v1.32.0"'

window.onload = () => {
    const root = document.querySelector(":root");
    root.style.setProperty("--release-version", JSON.stringify(releaseVersion))
    root.style.setProperty("--build-version", JSON.stringify(buildVersion))
    
    //cannot change label text with CSS
    document.querySelector("#app-version").innerHTML = releaseVersion
}
```

```css
:root {
    --release-version: "R0.0.0";
    --build-version: "v0.0.0";
}

/* https://css-tricks.com/swapping-out-text-five-different-ways/#aa-css-only-way */
#app-version {
    position: relative;
}
#app-version-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
#app-version-checkbox:checked + #app-version::after {
    content: var(--build-version);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<input id="app-version-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<label for="app-version-checkbox" id="app-version"></label>
```

Comment: @User1291 Many problems are obvious once you know the reason for it not working.